# AS3: Marking a variable for garbage collection, null or delete?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

If you have a variable that is a MovieClip, Sprite, String, Number, int, uint, or a Boolean, do you remove it's reference by adding:

```
myVariable = null;
```

OR

```
delete(myVariable);
```

Comment: I don't know AS, but unless AS grossly misuses the term "garbage collection", you shouldn't need either (see many similar questions for other GC'd languages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setting it to null is sufficient to remove a reference to the object it contained.

Note that the syntax of the `delete` operator is `delete object.member`, which removes `member` as a key from `object`, and as such will remove a reference to whatever it contains.

note that GC can only occur once *all* references to a given object are removed.

Comment: delete only removes dynamic objects.

Answer (score 4):

use `null`

delete won't work on variables that are not defined dynamically.

and always remember / never forget ... that you're nulling the reference NOT clearing the memory. meaning removing 1 reference is not always enough, you need to remove all references.

example:

```
var a:Object = {};
var b:Object = {};
a.name = "Alpha";
a.o = b;
b.name = "Beta";
b.o = b;

trace(b.name);
trace(a.o.name);
b = null;
trace(a.o.name);
trace(b.name);
```

while b doesn't exist anymore,  a.o (which is the object previously known as `b`) is still around.

so beware!!!

Comment: Do you have to do a.o = null; to clear out b? Or will a = null; suffice?

Comment: yes, think of an object variable as a pointer rather than a data structure. The data structure is in memory and will reside there until all references to it are removed. When no pointers exist, the data will be cleared on next garbage collection cycle

Comment: the trick to doing this kind of assignment is to never do this directly, but instead use functions that handle this assignment. the functions would then store information about what objects are connected, and when a destroy function is called, all references are removed. Have a look at how casaLib does it http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_display_CasaMovieClip.html
though the code is for managing eventlisteners, the idea is the same. track objects, and drop them inside destroy function

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but are you saying yes to the first question or are you saying yes that it will suffice?

Comment: sorry, I see how just the `yes` is confusing. Using `a.o = null` and `a = null` will both work in *this* case, but whether it will suffice in your application is hard to tell, so using both, `a.o = null; a = null;` is the safest bet. what you want to avoid is the 'Island of References' the author refers to in this article http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3--active-4412

Comment: Thanks a lot. The point about thinking about 'a' as a pointer to an object struct is very helpful.